# How do I save a file downloaded with HttpClient into a specific folder

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to download a PDF file with HttpClient. I am able to get the file but i am not sure how to convert the bytes into a a PDF and store it somewhere on the system

I have the following code, How can I store it as a PDF?

```
 public ???? getFile(String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                long len = entity.getContentLength();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // How do I write it?
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
String filePath = "sample.txt";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
int inByte;
while((inByte = is.read()) != -1)
     fos.write(inByte);
is.close();
fos.close();
```

---

**EDIT:**

you can also use [BufferedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) and [BufferedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) for faster download:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(entity.getContent());
String filePath = "sample.txt";
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath)));
int inByte;
while((inByte = bis.read()) != -1) bos.write(inByte);
bis.close();
bos.close();
```

Comment: HttpClient optimizes read operations internally. There is no need to use another buffering layer

Comment: I couldn't write directly to that file path, I had to use `File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"filename.jpg");` for writing to external storage so other apps could see my app

Answer (score 47):

Just for the record there are better (easier) ways of doing the same

```
File myFile = new File("mystuff.bin");

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet("http://host/stuff"))) {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        try (FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(myFile)) {
            entity.writeTo(outstream);
        }
    }
}
```

Or with the fluent API if one likes it better

```
Request.Get("http://host/stuff").execute().saveContent(myFile);
```

Comment: Witch package do i need to import for `Request.Get("http://host/stuff").execute().saveContent(myFile)`

Comment: In Maven you need the artifact `org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc` - the Java package is `org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request`

Answer (score 25):

Here is a simple solution using [`IOUtils.copy()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29):

```
File targetFile = new File("foo.pdf");

if (entity != null) {
    InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
}

return targetFile;
```

`IOUtils.copy()` is great because it handles buffering. However this solution is not very scalable:

- you cannot specify target file name and directory
- you might wish to store the files in a different way, e.g. in a database. Files aren't needed in this scenario.

Much more scalable solution involves two functions:

```
public void downloadFile(String url, OutputStream target) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{
    //...
    if (entity != null) {
    //...
        InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, target);
    }
}
```

And a helper method:

```
public void downloadAndSaveToFile(String url, File targetFile) {
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
    downloadFile(url, outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: Will this stream the file or hold the entire file in memory and then save to disk?

Answer (score 5):

Using dependency `org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc`:

```
Request.Get(url).execute().saveContent(file);
```

Request is from `org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request`.

In my case I needed a stream, this is equally simple:

```
inputStream = Request.Get(url).execute().returnContent().asStream();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Java 7+, you can use the native [Files.copy(InputStream in, Path target, CopyOption... options)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)), e.g.:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

try (InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent()) {
    Files.copy(inputStream, Paths.get(filePathString), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open a `FileOutputStream` and save the bytes from `inputStream` to it.

Comment: What's confusing me is that you have a FileOutputStream already open in the downloadAndSaveToFile method, but when I create the File object with the full path, I get a 'File does not exist' error ... can you show us code that would take this file which was downloaded and save it to a specific folder?

Comment: I apologize, I had a typo in my path. As it turns out, I can specify the file object with full desired path when the path is a VALID path.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Apache http client fluent API

```
Executor executor = Executor.newInstance().auth(new HttpHost(host), "user", "password"); 
executor.execute(Request.Get(url.toURI()).connectTimeout(1000)).saveContent("C:/temp/somefile");
```