# Why can't I create a File instance with this URI?

Tags: java, file, uri, mp3

Does anyone has an idea why this cast is not good:

```
URI myUri = URI.create("http://storage.googleapis.com/autoplay_audio/titanium.mp3");
File f = new File(myUri);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: FYI:  What you are doing is not casting.  You are creating a `URI` instance and then passing that to the constructor of `File.`  Casting would look something like `File f = (File) myUri;` which will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use anything other than a file uri (eg `file://`).

The constructor `File(URI)` has the following condition check:

```
String scheme = uri.getScheme();
if ((scheme == null) || !scheme.equalsIgnoreCase("file"))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("URI scheme is not \"file\"");
```

If you intend to connect to an `http` uri, you'll need to use some other mechanism, such as [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use File only for files. For your example to work, File would need to be aware of the HTTP protocol. You should use [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) or some other framework depending on your needs and environment.

Comment: The reason I do all this is because I want to get the audio's duration and I found a function that returns the duration of an audio file in Java File format.
How do you suggest me to do it best?

Comment: You can download the file with HttpClient for example, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960409/how-do-i-save-a-file-downloaded-with-httpclient-into-a-specific-folder). Then you can pass that File to the library which requires it.

Comment: The file is located in Google App Engine server. Isn't there a way to get the file duration without downloading the file?