# How to download files from a third party Rest end point in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, java-8, jira-rest-api

I want to download a file from a third party rest end-point in java

Sample CURL available from google and it is working as expected but I want to design it in java.
I tried googling it but could not get help.

Request method is "GET" and a multipart HTTP request

```
curl -L -O -k -u 'username:password' -X GET http://localhost:8080/secure/attachment/1461863/fileName.txt
```

Any sample code or link will do good.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I save a file downloaded with HttpClient into a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960409/how-do-i-save-a-file-downloaded-with-httpclient-into-a-specific-folder)

Comment: Thank you very much Mikhail - It was helpful and resolved my query

Comment: Sometimes it’s worth searching a bit before raising a new question  Glad to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use additional dependecies other than jdk, you can use something like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/secure/attachment/1461863/fileName.txt");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
    }
```